# Conditional Execution of Piepline in Azure DataFactory

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory

I need perform an "Execute Azure pipeline activity" based on a Condition. The condition is if a table in sql server return any rows i should execute the pipeline ,other wise i should skip the execution.How can get the row count of table  in Azure pipeline.Which activity i should use in order to get the Row Count of a table. Please let me know if can use any other options to do the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Lookup activity to determine whether the table has any rows.

1. Create a DataSet with no table and no schema:

[image]

[image]

2. Add a Lookup activity with that DataSet as the Source. Specify a Query to get the row count, and check "First row only":

[image]

3. Capture the output in a boolean variable (or reference it directly in the IF activity):

[image]

Note the syntax is *output.firstRow.*{sql_column_name}

Comment: Thank you for the input ,i will try this method.